# Dual boot with bitlocker Encryption Ubuntu 18.04 + Win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, encryption, windows-10, tpm

I see so many suggestions from blog related to bitlocker encryption dual boot ( Win 10 + ubuntu ) . But most of the cases, there is no success.

May I know how to proceed with working  dual boot encryption enabled.

Kindly let me know the step by step procedure, how to achieve this.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: you can check this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo